# SwiftUI Firebase Firestore Query Function

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have an array of SKU numbers that I'm returning from Google Firestore "[428024, 4298212]".

I have written a function assigning the array of SKU's to a variable, but I am lost as to how to return that variable from the function.

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()

func getItems() -> [Int]   {
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "nil"

    if (session.session != nil) {
        self.data.removeAll()
        db.collection("users").document(userID).getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                 let itemID = document.get("items") as! Array<Int>
               print(itemID as Any)
               // Prints "[428024, 4298212]"
                return itemID
                } else {
                    print("Document does not exist")
                    }
                }
        }      
}
```

I'm getting the error "Unexpected non-void return value in void function, though I can see that the array of SKU's are being returned when it runs the "print(itemID as Any)" line.

Is there any mistake in how I have the function written?

Comment: swift saying if session is nil or document dose not exists what will return your function?

Answer (score 1):

Querying the document through Firestore is written using a completion handler and trying to return any value from within this handler to your original function will deliver this error. Instead, you'll need to adjust your original function `getItems()` to account for this as such:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
@State private var itemIDs: [Int] = []

func getItems(completion: @escaping (_ itemIDs: [Int]?) -> ()) {

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "nil"

    if (session.session != nil) {
        self.data.removeAll()
        db.collection("users").document(userID).getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                 let itemIDs = document.get("items") as! Array<Int>
                 completion(itemIDs) // call completion handler to return value
            } else {
                 print("Document does not exist")
            }
        }
    }      
}


func callingYourFunction() {

    self.getItems() { itemIDs in 
        if let ids = itemIDs {
          // itemIDs exists -> do whatever else you originally intended to do with the ids
          self.itemIDs = ids
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/completion-handler-in-swift-4-2-671f12d33178) if you want to learn more about closures and completion handlers! Hopefully this helps.